# s3cmd restore giving error "no option -a"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I'm following the command from s3tools.org site, example provided for `-s` parameter.

but getting an error...

```
➜ s3cmd restore "s3://xxasdx-xxasdx-saip/originals" -s -days:7
Usage: s3cmd [options] COMMAND [parameters]

s3cmd: error: no such option: -a
```

What am I doing wrong here?!

Comment: There is no `-days:` option, perhaps you meant `--restore-days=7` (note the double `--`)

Comment: My apologies, I was looking the at s3express documentation and got applied it to s3cmd. Both are products of s3tools.

Comment: These days, it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`. I notice that s3cmd is [only updated about once per year](https://sourceforge.net/projects/s3tools/files/s3cmd/)

Comment: s3cmd was the first on my search results, so used it. I do realize it's worth switching over to AWS CLI soon. I typically don't work in AWS. But, I just had a one time personal backup restore job where I had to recur over folders. So ended up with whatever came first.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the bad question, it was my stupidity. I was looking at `s3express` documentation while using `s3cmd` tool.

Both tools produced by s3tools.org and the left menu is a little confusing with only one item named "Manual". For the s3cmd it's called usage.